# Split a string using Regular Expression

Tags: .net, regex

I have a string like:

```
personname=aanch&personaddress=Jammu & Kashmir&personmobile=9876543210
```

My desired output is:

```
personname=aanch
personaddress=Jammu & Kashmir
personmobile=9876543210
```

Is it possible to use a Regular Expression to split the string on `&` and get the result above?

Comment: Not directly, but you can split it and then make a second pass which merges the shorter ones with their neighbours

Comment: if its AB&CD&EFG then what should be the output ?

Comment: If the string is not of any fixed size, like ABC&DE&F&GH&I and I want the output string like ABC DE F GH&I............& here is an character not separator...

Comment: @aanch: The rules are still not clear, at least to me. Can you define exactly when a `&` should be split on (and when not)?

Comment: i mean as in you example last two chars P & Q are splitted and joined with & as the length or you just want P and Q different ?

Comment: sorry i made a mistake in my last comment, see my first post...there will not be any space in before and after the &.

Comment: @aanch how can we know that which & is separator and which is a character?

Comment: @aanch and what about JK&L? there is no any white space..

Comment: actually in my program I have got such scenario with details of some person. I have to extract those value from that concatinated string and fill different fields with respective value. so my question is also that how can we know that which & is separator and which is character? one string which I got till now have the string like this........personname=aanch&personcompany=abcd&personaddress=abcd & efgh&personmobile=1234567890......

Comment: I need the o/p like:............personname=aanch           personcompany=abcd          personaddress=abcd & efgh        personmobile=1234567890

Comment: @aanch: Don't use the comments to explain what you meant by your question. Edit your question instead. And please provide meaningful examples.

Comment: Sorry to all, I am new to Stack Overflow so, I have made some mistake to ask a question...

Comment: If this is a query string, then `&` cannot appear unescaped in there, as far as I know. Are you doing percent-decoding first and now try damage control?

Answer (score 2):

With the re-edit of the question, I do see a solution that might actually work:

```
splitArray = Regex.Split(subjectString, 
    @"&    # Split on a &
    (?=    # but only if it's followed by...
     \w+   # a series of alphanumeric characters
     =     # and an equals sign
    )      # End of lookahead assertion", 
    RegexOptions.IgnorePatternWhitespace);
```

Answer (score 0):

EDIT - With the change of question

```
 var regex = new Regex(@"&(?<=[^&=]+=)")
```

Which the break down is

& - match &

(?<=[^&=]+=) - Match but don't include atleast one character that isn't & or = followed by =

Alternatively if you actually after the names and values you can do the following

```
var regex=new Regex(@"(?>^|&)(?<name>.*?)=(?<value>.*?)(?=$|&[^&]+?=)");
var text="personname=aanch&personaddress=Jammu & Kashmir&personmobile=9876543210";
foreach (Match match in regex.Matches(text)) {
    var name=match.Groups["name"].Value;
    var value=match.Groups["value"].Value;
    // Do something with values
}
```

Comment: the criteria is not clear as aanch said that & which is covered with spaces is considered as a character not a separator.

Comment: @HemantMetalia The comments in the question were not visible when I posted, I've now added an edit, but I agree the JK&L example does not seem to the OP criteria

Answer (score -1):

But why do you need reg-ex to split the string. You can use normal C# string split function to get the desired result

```
string text = "ABC&DEF&GHI&JK&L&MNO&P&Q"
var splitString = text.split(text,"&");
```

The splitted string will be stored as an array in `splitString`

Comment: have you gone through the op of the question?